# Validating password and confirm password in PHP

Tags: php, validation, passwords

I am trying a registration form where password and confirm password should match each other. If it doesn't match it should display error message. And how to validate password to more than 6 characters? 
How can i do this? How to validate password and confirm password to be matched and display error message password is wrong?

Here is the code

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$db = "reg";
//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db($db,$dbhandle) or die('cannot select db');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

     $name= $_POST['name'];

     $username= $_POST['username'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];
     $cpassword= $_POST['cpassword'];

     if($name==''){
     echo "<script>alert('Please enter Name')
     </script>";
    exit();
    }
    if($username==''){
     echo "<script>alert('Please enter Username')
     </script>";
    exit();
    }
    if($password=='' && $password<6){
     echo "<script>alert('Please enter  Password')</script>";

    exit();
    }

    if($cpassword==''){
     echo "<script>alert('Please enter Confirm Password')
     </script>";

    }



    $check_name="select * from registration where username='$username'";
    $run=mysql_query($check_name);

     if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){
    echo "<script>alert('Username $username already exits in our database. Please try with Another!')</script>";

    }

    elseif($password != $cpassword){
       echo "<script>alert('passwords doesn't match')</script>";
    }
    else{
          $query = "INSERT INTO `registration` (name,username, password,cpassword) VALUES ('$name','$username', '$password', '$cpassword')";
          $run1=mysql_query($query);

    if($run1){
    echo "<script>window.open('register.html','_self')</script>";
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

HTML CODE

```
 <form name="register"  action="register.php" method="POST" id="register" style="font-family:ff-meta-web,Arial,sans-serif;text-align:justify;line-height:25px; font-size:12px;">
    <label style="margin-right:30px;"> <b> Name : </b></label>

    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" style="width:200px;" /> 
    <br /> <br />

    <label> <b> User Name : </b></label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" style="width:200px;" /> <br/><br/>
    <label> <b> Password : </b></label> 
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="width:200px;" />
    <br /> <br /> 
    <label> <b>Confirm Password : </b></label> 
    <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" style="width:200px;" />
    <br /> <br /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="background-color:#005797; color:#fff; border:0px; padding:5px 10px;" /> 

    </form>
```

Comment: Why you are doing the check in server side? You can do this on your client side and so the alert message.

Comment: Post your HTML code and Javascript code too, so that can help on this.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if($password=='' && $password<6){
```

to

```
if($password=='' && strlen($password)<6){
```

You should validate all your inputs on client side also.

Answer (score 0):

if($password=='' && strlen($password)<6){ echo "your error mesaage";}elseif($password!=$cpassword){echo "error meassage";}
you can show error message like this

Comment: It redirects to another page with password is less then 6 characters. and password and confirm password doesnt match

Comment: if you want validation after filling the particular field use jquery or javascript